# How to crawl image from using url?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to extract the images from url by below python code but after extraction, at last point, I am getting the following error:

```
OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

how to remove this error.

Python code is:

```
 import sys
    import requests 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time
    import base64
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    url='https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    imgs = {}
    
    for i in range(1,10):
        res=requests.get(url,timeout=60,headers=headers)
       
        imgs[i]=res.content
    
        jpg_original = base64.b64decode(res.content)
        jpg_as_np = np.frombuffer(jpg_original, dtype=np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(jpg_as_np, flags=1)
        cv2.imwrite('./0.jpg', img)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You did not explain what the actual problem is.

Comment: i don't know to get image @KlausD.